# How to check whether file exits or not?

Tags: java, file, filesystems

I am trying to save contents in file but first I want to search either file does exist or not.  But the code I have written, every time it is returning true.

```
String fileName=FNameTextField.getText();

File file=new File(fileName);

if(file.exists()&& !file.isDirectory()) {
    // It returns true if File or directory does exist
    System.out.println("the file or directory  you are searching does  exist : " );

}else{
    // It returns true if File or directory not exists
    System.out.println("the file or directory you are searching does not  exist : " );
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: I _strongly_ suggest you consider avoiding use of `java.io.File` in favor of the new API introduced in Java 7. In particular, [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/check.html) is the relevant Sun Java Trail tutorial for solving this problem. The method of importance is [Files.exists](http://goo.gl/SRTWb).

Answer (score 1):

Your logic seems to be all screwy, or at least I can't make heads or tails of it

```
if (file.exists()) {
   if (file.isDirectory) {
        System.out.println("Directory already exists");
   } else {
        System.out.println("File exists");
   }
} else {
   System.out.println("Could not find a file or directory matching your request");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using method...

```
file.isFile()
```

The javadoc says

*Tests whether the file denoted by this abstract pathname is a normal file. A file is normal if it is not a directory and, in addition, satisfies other system-dependent criteria. Any non-directory file created by a Java application is guaranteed to be a normal file.*

Answer (score 0):

Your logic checks if to see only if it is a file. It will NOT return true if a directory with the name exists as you imply in your print statements.

Answer (score 0):

Make use of this examples which is adopt for you :

```
File f = new File(filePathString);
if(f.exists()) { /* do something */ }


         (or)

import java.io.*;

public class FileChecker {

  public static void main(String args[]) {

      File f = new File("c:\\mkyong.txt");

      if(f.exists()){
          System.out.println("File existed");
      }else{
          System.out.println("File not found!");
      }

  }

} 

               (or)

import java.io.*;

public class FileOrDirectoryExists{
  public static void main(String args[]){
  File file=new File("Any file name or 
   directory whether exists or not");
  boolean exists = file.exists();
  if (!exists) {
  // It returns false if File or directory does not exist
  System.out.println("the file or directory 
  you are searching does not exist : " + exists);

  }else{
  // It returns true if File or directory exists
  System.out.println("the file or 
  directory you are searching does exist : " + exists);
  }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**1.** First **get all the files** in the folder, and store it in an `ArrayList`.

**Eg:**

```
   File f = new File("d:\\MyFolder);

   File[] fArr = f.listFiles();

   ArrayList<File> fList = new ArrayList<File>();

   for ( File file : fArr){

         if (file.isFile()){

                fList.add(file);

           }else{

                continue;

            }

   }
```

**2.** Now use `getName()` method to check the **file exists or not**....

**Assume** you are looking for a file named `"vivek.txt"`

**Eg:**

boolean b = false;

```
for (File i : fList){


   if ((i.getName).equals("vivek.txt")){


           b = true;
           break;


       }

   else{

               continue;
      }



   }
```